# Passing a referenced node's location token to referring node

Tags: entities, 6, tokens, nodes

I have two content types -- Invoice and Project -- which are related to each other (Basic content types provided by [Storm](http://drupal.org/project/storm)). Project has a Location CCK field, which I want to use in the Invoice's title field (via [Automatic Node Titles](http://drupal.org/project/auto_nodetitle)).

**How would I pass the Project's location field value (Specifically street address) to the referring Invoice via Automatic Node Title field?**

Thank you!